# Red-flagged question titles are no longer shown to moderators

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, spam

Instead of the title, I just see "This question was marked as spam or rude or abusive and is therefore not shown":

[image: Screenshot of the top of a question, with "This question was marked as spam or rude or abusive and is therefore not shown" as the title; below, it shows a post notice saying "This post is hidden. It was flagged as spam or offensive content and deleted 3 mins ago by Community [Bot]."]

While this is the correct behavior for non-moderators, moderators are supposed to see the full content of the post.  This is working correctly for the post body, which is shown, but appears to have recently broken for the title.  When evaluating flagged posts, it's very helpful to be able to see the title.  Could this be fixed?

Comment: The [NSFW user script](https://stackapps.com/questions/8082/request-for-user-script-to-remove-mask-from-posts-deleted-as-spam-or-offensive) (meant for non-mods who don't want spam masking) also broke. I think a class name changed making both that script and the (possible) client-side JS used to show the title for mods break.

Comment: @Sonic thanks for the pings, I've updated the script (v0.6) so that it works again. Let's hope when SE fixes this bug it doesn't need another update :)

Comment: Based on the above code change, it seems like SE removed the CSS class (not just renamed, but *removed* it) that indicated that a post was deleted as spam or offensive. I think the title is rendered based on client-side JS that checks for that CSS class, and that JS wasn't updated to reflect the removal of that class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whoops, my bad. The fix has been merged and will go out with the next production build.

Thanks for the report!

Comment: Why was the CSS class for spam-masked posts removed? This broke a user script that removes masks on such posts for non-moderators, and while the developer fixed it, the current fix depends on the wordings of the post deletion notice and masked post message to detect a masked post, meaning it would break again if those wordings are changed, and would require more work to function on the international sites due to their wordings being in different languages. It would be nice to have that CSS class back so scripts that work on masked posts can continue to work properly and be more maintainable.